# "Uncaught ReferenceError: getWeather is not defined",

Tags: javascript, android, webview

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.notifyweather.net23.net/");
```

Javascript will not run in some mobile phones and 
log cat shows the following error:

> INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: getWeather is not
>   defined", source: http://www.notifyweather.net23.net/js/weather.js
>   (10)

Comment: Because in that page there is no a getWeather() function in all js files.

Comment: But I have called the .getWeather function .